# XSLT streaming not streaming

Tags: streaming, saxon, xslt-3.0

I'm using `Saxon-EE` for the purpose of streaming XSLT transformation of large XML. The transformation works fine but it seems it's not really streaming since the java.exe process is inflating: for a `100 MB` XML, process memory increases ~`1GB`. This is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                          xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                          xmlns:bb="urn:xx-zz-1.1"
                          xmlns:aa="urn:xx-yy-1.1">
<xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="aa:LevelOne/aa:LevelTwo">
        <xsl:iterate select="bb:LevelThree! copy-of(.)">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(bb:fieldOne,',',bb:fieldTwo,'&#xA;')"/>
        </xsl:iterate>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<aa:LevelOne xmlns="urn:xx-zz-1.1" xmlns:aa="urn:xx-yy-1.1">
  <aa:LevelTwo xmlns="urn:xx-zz-1.1" xmlns:aa="urn:xx-yy-1.1">
    <LevelThree xmlns="urn:xx-zz-1.1">
      <fieldOne>f1</fieldOne>
      <fieldTwo>f2</fieldTwo>
    </LevelThree>
    <!-- Level three is repeated many times -->
  </aa:LevelTwo>
</aa:LevelOne>
```

I would like to know if there (& what) is a problem with the XSLT above.

The code I use:

```
    net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor processor = new net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor(true);
    processor.setConfigurationProperty(Feature.STREAMABILITY, "standard");
    XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
    XsltExecutable stylesheet = compiler.compile(new StreamSource(stylesheetFile));
    Serializer out = processor.newSerializer(outputCsvFile);
    Xslt30Transformer transformer = stylesheet.load30();
    transformer.applyTemplates(new StreamSource(xmlFile), out);
```

**EDIT:** Fixed the XSLT so it compiles & added XML example.

Remark: using command `java -cp "<path>\test;<path>\saxon9ee.jar" com.example.test.Test -t` does not ouput additional info (only the `println`s in  the code). `java -cp "<path>\test;<path>\saxon9ee.jar" -t com.example.test.Test` outputs: `Unrecognized option: -Xt Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine`. If I change the XSLT to non-streamable rule e.g. remove the `iterate` line, program outputs `Template rule is not streamable`, also without `-t` option. In this case if I remove the streamability requirement from code/xslt, the error goes away.

Thanks.

Comment: Does Saxon 9 EE (which version exactly do you use?) show you that the XSLT passes the streamability analysis and it is streaming the source document if you run it from the command line with option `-t`?

Comment: I think, from within a Java application, if you set http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/lib/Feature.html#TIMING, you should see on standard error any indication that the `-t` option on the command line emits, like whether it is streaming the source document.

Comment: License is set fine (also checked with isSechemaAware). Adding -t (At the end of the command) does not output anything. (Saxon 9.1.4).

Comment: The `t` option does output a lot of details for me, like Java or .NET version, Saxon version and license number, and then the way it loads and parses stylesheet and input (including whether it streams it) so I kind of don't understand why you don't get any output. Can you edit your question to show us minimal but complete details of an XML, a working XSLT (`bb:fieldTwo'` in your sample does not even compile), the exact command line and the result you get, so that we can reproduce it?

Comment: Presumably you meant Saxon 9.9.1.4, not Saxon 9.1.4?

Comment: Also, for completeness: a possible explanation which is perhaps unlikely, but is not inconsistent with the information provided, is that there are very few bb:levelThree elements and they are very large.

Comment: Edited the question, also added the command

Comment: My suggestion to use the `-t` option to get details about streaming is meant to be used with the Saxon 9 command line interface e.g. `java saxon9ee.jar -t -xsl:yoursheet.xsl -s:yourxml.xml -o:result.csv`. That should tell you whether the XSLT code is considered streamable and then also show whether the XSLT processes the input XML with streaming and later output the memory usage. I understand you want to use Saxon in your own Java code but the suggestions was meant to allow you to first check/try the XSLT with Saxon's command line interface and diagnostics before diving into using it in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most likely reason Saxon would fall back to non-streaming mode is that it hasn't located a Saxon-EE license. The easiest way to test that is (unintuitively!) by calling `processor.isSchemaAware()` - that will only be true if you're running Saxon-EE code with a recognized license, which is exactly the same condition to enable streaming.

If it hasn't found a license, the Saxon documentation includes a section on troubleshooting license problems at http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!about/license

Also, try it from the command line with option -t; that will give you more information (a) about streaming, and (b) about loading of license files.

Comment: License is set fine (also checked with isSechemaAware). Adding -t (At the end of the command) does not output anything.

Comment: Perhaps the reason -t doesn't output anything is because standard error output is redirected? Or you've entered the command using some kind of environment that doesn't display console output?

Answer (score 0):

I think, if the data is as simple and as regular as shown in the question, then you can avoid the use of `copy-of()` and simply use

```
        <xsl:iterate select="bb:LevelThree">
            <xsl:value-of select="bb:*" separator=","/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:iterate>
```

That in a quick test shows a reduced memory consumption compared to your posted approach.

As for your posted approach not using streaming with Saxon EE 9.9, I have tested the posted XSLT and the input sample with Saxon 9.9 EE from the command line with the `-t` option and it shows the input is streamed.

I also think the Java code shown is fine to process the file with streaming with Saxon EE.

For a detailed analysis of the memory consumption and any problems you encounter with that it might be better to raise an issue with all details on the Saxonica support site. I am not sure how the memory info Saxon outputs relates exactly to the one you say you see for `java.exe`.